# How can you implement new @for @if syntax introduced in Angular 17 in PUG?

Tags: angular, pug

I have been using PUG in my Angular application and I like the new syntax introduced in Angular 17 regarding @for and @if, replacing *ngFor and *ngIf.  I wasn't sure how to implement this via PUG.

When I try to implement it via pug by typing in @for, I get an error:

```
unexpected text "@for("
```

Maybe I need to wait for a newer version of pug?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the issues for [ngx-pug-builders](https://github.com/lekhmanrus/ngx-pug-builders/issues/10#issuecomment-1768867391)

The short answer is that you put a '|' at the start of the so-called control flow lines. Note that you do not indent the first line of the control flow block:

```
|@if(a>b) {
div() 
|}
```